# \raggedleft having no effect in group

Tags: horizontal-alignment

the following code produce a text flushed to the left of the page, which I did not expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\raggedleft Xyzzy!}
\end{document}
```

like so:

[image: with group]

Removing the group produce what I expected.
Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\raggedleft Xyzzy!
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: without group]

What did I got wrong?

Comment: You need a closing `\par` inside the group for the `\raggedleft` to take effect.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: please turn this comment into an answer and I would be glad to accept it.